# Creating Matrix in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Python  Notebook with a data matrix with data on the
appearances of certain words in an SFrame document. The column names
are ['great', 'bad',....] and each row has the number of appearences
on different rows of the list ( sorry , I am having trouble getting a
screenshot from the VM). So the row values are non-negative integers
0,1,2,...

I want to create a matrix with 2 columns and 11 rows.Each row has two entries:
One containing the name of each word and the other entry containing the total count of the word (sum over all rows for the fixed column).  The words are part of a list called 'Selected Words' . I am kind of clueless,
I know how to create new columns for an existing SFrame, but no clue for how to create a new SFrame, or some other Python Data Structure. The best I have is :

```
 for word in selected_words:
    count[word]=products[word].sum()
    print [word, count[word]]
```

I have also thought of creating a matrix in some other file format and importing it . But then I don't know how to

Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: do you have to use SFrame? pandas might be easier

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is to create a Python dictionary.

'selected_words' is a Python list of your words, so just iterate over each word and build the dict with each key word and sum of occurrences.

```
totals = {}
for word in selected_words:
    totals[word] = products[word].sum()
```

Then you can just type `totals` in IPython and it will give you the dictionary with each word and it's count.